# Compare string value against array of strings in PHP/ Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I want to match string with array. I am retrieving the status code from status table in the database...I have a json file with code and name...Based on the status code returned from db i need to match this code in json file and display the status name in foreach

Please anyone help

Thanks

*statuscodes array*

```
[
 {
     "code":"0",
     "name":"AB"
   },
   {
     "code":"1",
     "name":"CD"
   },
   {
     "code":"2",
     "name":"XY"
   },
   {
     "code":"10",
     "name":"EF"
   },
   {
     "code":"12",
     "name":"FG"
   }
 ]

 <?php $findproducts = \DB::table('status')->select('id', 'status_name', 'ab', 'status_code','created_at')->where('ab', $track->ab)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get(); ?>
```

String Pos....

```
 @foreach($findproducts as $pr) 
  @if($statuscodes != null)
   @foreach ($statuscodes as $stcode) 
     @if (strpos($pr->status_code, $stcode['code']) !== FALSE) 
       {{ $stcode['name']." " .$stcode['code'] }}                                                             
     @endif
   @endforeach
@endif
@endforeach
```

**The output which i am getting from above is**
CD 1 XY 2 FG 12
CD 1 AB 0 EF 10
XY 2
CD 1
AB 0
**Expected Output should be**
FG 12
EF 10
XY 2
CD 1
AB 0

Comment: You can just change `orderBy('id', 'DESC')` to `orderBy('code', 'DESC')`?

Comment: @Johannes i tried but i am getting same output

Comment: Your outer loop is looping through all products, so if first product has status codes `1`, `2` and `12` it will output these. If I got your expected output correctly you want to output the `statuscodes` array elements and not the products, correct?

Comment: @Johannes yes exactly...if the code is 12 i just wanna print status name FG thats it....but its looping through 1 and next 2 then 12 which is wrong

Comment: I am absolutely confused why are you doing `strpos($pr->status_code, $stcode['code'])`. Can you explain more what you want to do as your example is not understandable by me... What do you really want to do ? Also what version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: i have updated my question @matiaslauriti.....i am retrieving the status code based on ab   number and matching this status code in json file and retrieving the status name from json file...PHP version 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing:

```php
@if (strpos($pr->status_code, $stcode['code']) !== FALSE)
    {{ $stcode['name']." ".$stcode['code'] }}
@endif
```

Instead of:

```php
@if ($pr->status_code === $stcode['code'])
    {{ $stcode['name']." ".$stcode['code'] }}
@endif
```

---

I think your problem is [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (I am not sure why you are using it). As the documentation says: `Prior to PHP 8.0.0, if needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character. This behavior is deprecated as of PHP 7.3.0, and relying on it is highly discouraged. Depending on the intended behavior, the needle should either be explicitly cast to string, or an explicit call to chr() should be performed.`

I am not sure if your needle is being used as a number so it is messing things up...

Also, when the `if` is true and you print what you want, you can break the `foreach` so you don't waste time nor effort on iterating something that you know will never be true again until something changes. You can do so using `@break`.

```php
@if($statuscodes != null)
    @foreach($findproducts as $pr)
        @foreach ($statuscodes as $stcode)
            @if ($pr->status_code === $stcode['code'])
                {{ $stcode['name']." ".$stcode['code'] }}
                @break
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

See also that I have switched the `foreach` with the first `if`, because if you do not have `$statuscodes`, why are you going to iterate `$findproducts` and skip everything ? Don't even iterate it...

Comment: yeah i tried with this finally got the desired result tq

Answer (score 1):

try this , it is more cleaner

first convert status code to collection and convert it so collection of key=> value pairs

this should be the status code collection
[image]

then look up your key using simple foreach loop.

Note I am not sure what is returned from database  so you can change the code to suite the desired output.

also try to avoid nested loops as much as you can

```
$status_code = collect(json_decode('[
 {
     "code":"0",
     "name":"AB"
   },
   {
     "code":"1",
     "name":"CD"
   },
   {
     "code":"2",
     "name":"XY"
   },
   {
     "code":"10",
     "name":"EF"
   },
   {
     "code":"12",
     "name":"FG"
   }]'
 ,true))->pluck('code','name');



@foreach($findproducts as $pr)
{{$pr->status_code ." ". $status_code[$pr->status_code]}}
@endforeach
```